# getDay javascript if not work in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

But do not work please help
I just want to tell if today is Sunday adding the class calDisable

This source

https://github.com/Thibor/jsRapCalendar

in this code I want to cancel on Sunday

i try in

```
this.week = this.opt.date.getDay();


    if(this.week == 4)
        d.addClass('calDisable');
```

Comment: Why would 4 be a Sunday? Although... it would be nice to have a day off midweek.

Answer (score 1):

the `getDay()` method is zero-indexed, and Sunday is the first day of the week, so you need to run whatever code you need when `this.week === 0`

- 0 = Sunday
- 1 = Monday
- 2 = Tuesday
- 3 = Wednesday
- 4 = Thursday
- 5 = Friday
- 6 = Saturday

Answer (score 0):

`this.week = this.opt.date.getDay();
        if(this.week === 0)
            d.addClass('calDisable');`

This should work. Not sure why are you comparing to 4 since 4 represents Thursday.

> The value returned by the Javascript getDay() method is an integer corresponding to the day of the week. It will be 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ..... , 5 for Friday and 6 for Saturday.